# Incorporating sendEmailVerification method in frontend handler or backend signup method?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I'm trying to incorporate an email verification step in the signing up process of my app. Looking at the docs online, seems like doing it in the front-end seems like the way to go.

Problem is the examples I see online have the entire sign in process done in the front-end, and just simply include the the sendEmailVerification method.

*sendEmailVerification Method*

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
  // Email sent.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

I (instead) built my sign up method in the backend and its respective handler in the front.

*Front-End Sign Up Handler*

```
authHandler = () => {
  const authData = {
      email: this.state.controls.email.value,
      password: this.state.controls.password.value
  };
  this.props.onTryAuth(authData, this.state.authMode);
  // ontTryAuth is a backend action that creates new users in Firebase
};
```

Is it a good idea to include the sendEmailVerification method into this front-end handler code? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it. First this method is built by Firebase because people who use Firebase don't always/never have a server. You can yes build your own signup method in your server, but why you would use Firebase if you start to override all the stuff they give you? For me I see Firebase as a prototyping tool and so I use all the features they give, so that let me put an app working faster.

Let me know if that make sense.

Comment: I get what you mean. The problem is that when I first built the app, I used a tutorial I learned from Udemy, and the lecturer created a back-end auth rather than just using firebase. But now, I want to fast track with the email verification, and because I'm still very new to coding and RN, I want to use firebase sendEmailVerification method. Problem is that I don't know if it will cause problems down the track or not.